# Visual Studio "Run button" changed to "Attach to a process"

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging

I am trying to run a C code in microsoft visual studio 2015. 
For some reason, the run bottom is changed to "Attach to a process".
And when I attach any of the process, the process wouldn't start to run (command prompt would'nt open).

That's a picture of my visual studio and the attach to process window:

[image]

Comment: Great work erasing those data. :P

Comment: Is this an .exe project or a DLL? DLL-s cannot run by themselves, they need an executable that loads them.

Comment: Don't worry, no one will notice that you username is `ghaderi`.  ;)

Comment: To complete what @xxbbcc wrote, if your project is an executable file, is the executable running, if not, can it be runned on your computer? (32/64 arch problem, missing dll...)

Comment: The project doesn't show any source files. Assuming the source file is in the project folder, click on the project tab, then add existing item, then click on the source file name. Then build the project and then run or debug the project. Normally you don't use attach to process unless it's a multi-process solution.

Answer (score 1):

May be because the code you have compiled gives only a Dynamic Link Library (DLL) file. So you need to attach it to a process (`.exe` file) which will load the (DLL) for execution.

Also, why 0 projects?

[image: Project]

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was exactly what was mentioned here. I just opened a C code in visual studio. I had to create a project beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10. Adding dotnet path as a system varible solved my problem.

This may be helpful for others;

1. Right click on **This PC** and select properties.
2. Click the **Advanced system settings**.
3. Then click the **Environment Variables**.
4. In the **System Variables** section, find the **PATH** environment variable and select it. Click Edit.
5. Click **New** and paste your dotnet path (my path is **C:\Program Files\dotnet**)

Answer (score 0):

It helped me. Only instead of adding a new variable, it is worth checking if it is already registered in the PATH variable. In addition to seeing if there are two routes to the same donet:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet (This should be first)
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34021254)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project, make sure you tick "Place solution and project in the same directory".